# CSS Animation timing issue on modal close

Tags: css

I am using a w3Schools tutorial for a modal. I would like to run an animation after the user clicks the close button. I am using a blind animation and have it working on open but would like the reverse on close.

Should I be using Javascript to change the classes inline? I've experimented with that but the animation doesn't have time to run because I'm closing the modal with `display:hidden` right after the animation call, so it's being executed before the animation has time to complete.

Here is my html. I have the animation class inline and the only thing I can think of is to switch the `out` animation with javascript:

```
<div id="modal-one" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content modal-parent blind-content in origin-middle">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h2>header</h2>
      <span class="modal-close"></span>
    </div>
    content here
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the blind effect to run on open and close?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next time please provide a link to the tutorial (or some such).

You could use javascript.

change your html to...

```
<div id="modal-one" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content modal-parent blind-content in origin-middle">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h2>header</h2>
      <span class="modal-close d-none"></span>
      <span class="model-close-dummy"></span>
    </div>
    content here
  </div>
</div>
```

then add javascript

```
let modal = document.querySelector("#modal-one");
let modal_close_dummy = modal.querySelector(".modal-close-dummy")
let modal_close = modal.querySelector(".modal-close")

modal_close_dummy.addEventListener("click", function () {
   runClosingAnimation();//run animation - do what you need to do
   setTimeout(function(){
      modal_close.click(); //programatically click the actual close button after 500ms
   }, 500) //500 time in miliseconds to wait, before the stuff inside setTimeout runs
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: WeAreDoomed, truth to your name btw. :)  That's what I was thinking...this is going to be a javascript fix. I just wanted wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some CSS property that would do this for me. I also had the idea to use setTimeout for this as well but felt I was digging myself a hole and was why I posted first.

Comment: Can you explain why you're using a dummy span instead of tapping off the physical one?

Comment: I know right ;P I assume the physical one actually closes the modal, but If you click on a dummy modal which does nothing, you can run the animation and then programatically click the actual close-modal.

Comment: you could try with a "pseudo" class ::active (css), but if it's ::active, it means you've already clicked on the element so I assume it's going to close.